# Second-order non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$2tx'-x=lnx'$

I differentiated both sides with respect to x:

$x'+2tx''=\frac {x''}{x'}$

Substituting $p=x'$,

$p+2tp'=\frac{p'}{p}$

But I have no clue what can I do from here on.

EDIT: $t$ is the non-dependent variable.

Comment: Is $t$ a constant or a variable?

Comment: Write it in the form of an exact equation, then try to find an integrating factor http://www.cliffsnotes.com/math/differential-equations/first-order-equations/integrating-factors

Comment: Ok I solved that exact equation, but I have no idea how to solve the result for $p$:
$p^2t-p=C$

Answer (score 1):

I would say that

$x=2tp-\ln p$

$x'=2tp'+ 2p-\frac{p'}{p}$

$2tp'+ p-\frac{p'}{p}=0 \Rightarrow t'+\frac{2t}{p}=\frac{1}{p^2},\,$ie linear equation for t, $\Rightarrow t=\frac{p+C}{p^2}$

Substituting the 't' in the first equation we have parametric equations for x, t (parameter = p):

$x=2\frac{p+C}{p}-\ln p,\,\,\,t = \frac{p+C}{p^2}$

Answer (score 0):

If you are studying differential equations, you certainly should know how to solve a quadratic equation!
$tp^2- p- C= 0$ so, by the quadratic formula, $p= \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4Ct}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the method in http://www.ae.illinois.edu/lndvl/Publications/2002_IJND.pdf#page=2:

Let $F(t,x,s)=2ts-\ln s-x$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dt}{ds}=-\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial s}}{\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}+s\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}}=-\dfrac{2t-\dfrac{1}{s}}{2s+s(-1)}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{s}-2t}{s}=\dfrac{1}{s^2}-\dfrac{2t}{s}$

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}+\dfrac{2t}{s}=\dfrac{1}{s^2}$

I.F.$=e^{\int\frac{2}{s}ds}=e^{2\ln s}=s^2$

$\therefore\dfrac{d(s^2t)}{ds}=1$

$s^2t=\int ds$

$s^2t=s+C_1$

$t=\dfrac{1}{s}+\dfrac{C_1}{s^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{dx}{ds}=st=1+\dfrac{C_1}{s}$

$x=\int\left(1+\dfrac{C_1}{s}\right)ds$

$x=s+C_1\ln s+C_2$

Hence $\begin{cases}t=\dfrac{1}{s}+\dfrac{C_1}{s^2}\\x=s+C_1\ln s+C_2\end{cases}$